# Understand existing Postgres WAL archiving setup filling up the disk

Tags: postgresql

New to a certain Postgres implementation done by someone else and need help figuring out an issue.

We have the following archive command configured,  If I understand correctly then the archive command copies WAL files to a mounted storage /mnt/database:

```
archive_command = 'if { egrep -q " /mnt/database .* rw," /proc/mounts ;} && { ! pgrep test -u postgres ;} ; then test ! -f /mnt/database/%f && cp %p /mnt/database/%f ; else exit 1; fi'
```

We then have a cron job to move corrupted WALs out of the way:

```
find /mnt/database -type f  -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*[A-Z0-9]{24}$" -mmin +60 -size -16777216c -exec logger "Trimming Postgres WAL Logs" \; -exec find /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_xlog/{} -type f \; -exec mv {} {}.incomplete \;
```

The issue we are having is the /mnt/database keeps filling up and we need to extend the disk every few days. Is that because we have excessive WAL writing or too many corrupted WAL files ?

Answer (score 0):

The live WAL in 'pg_wal' cleans itself up automatically.  Your WAL archive, '/mnt/database/' here, does not.  It is up to you to arrange for that to get cleaned up based on your organization's retention policy.

If your policy is to keep WAL forever, then you need to get enough storage space to do that.  If you have some other policy, you would need to understand what it is (and describe it to us, if you want our help implementing it)

Neither of the commands you show seem to be related to retention.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the first command moves the WAL files to /mnt/database while the second one ensures they are being rotated. Since we are taking base backups every 24 hours the policy is to retain the WAL files in /mnt/database for 24 hours. Does that help ?